# FFT-Phase variation of a signal

Tags: fft, linear-phase

I was studying the phase variation of a signal using sliding window FFT generated using below python code. The phase variation produced for my signal starts from somewhere in middle of the signal cycle (indicated by black circles) however the phase angle for a simple smooth up and down signal starts with the cycle itself. I am not able to understand why the phase variation is not starting from the start of the cycle for my signal. What is the logic or intuition behind this?

**MY SIGNAL WITH CORRESPONDING PHASE VARIATION:**
[image]

**SINE WAVE WITH CORRESPONDING PHASE VARIATION**
[image]

**CODE**

```
signal = np.array([15.6, 16.82, 20.53, 24.08, 26.48, 27.75, 28.14, 28.27, 28.31, 28.12, 27.94, 27.51, 27.1, 26.43, 25.77, 25.06, 24.14, 23.39, 22.53, 21.68, 20.87, 20.2, 19.29, 18.58, 17.87, 17.46, 16.75, 16.2, 15.81, 15.34, 14.91, 14.61, 14.49, 14.33, 14.24, 14.32, 14.4, 14.63, 14.88, 15.19, 15.54, 15.72, 16.04, 16.53, 16.96, 17.28, 17.34, 17.46, 17.43, 16.66, 16.55, 16.46, 16.32, 16.15, 16.09, 16.11, 16.09, 16.04, 16.01, 16.09, 16.1, 16.04, 16.02, 16.01, 16.01, 16.02, 16.02, 16.04, 16.09, 16.15, 16.1, 16.04, 16.01, 16.01, 15.93, 15.84, 15.9, 15.99, 15.87, 15.85, 15.86, 15.9, 15.83, 15.84, 15.84, 15.85, 15.77, 15.76, 15.77, 15.77, 15.76, 15.76, 15.84, 15.85, 15.9, 15.87, 15.87, 15.84, 15.79, 15.76, 15.69, 15.68, 15.68, 15.68, 15.69, 15.69, 15.69, 15.62, 15.46, 15.49, 15.5, 15.59, 15.7, 15.73, 15.84, 15.84, 15.78, 15.77, 15.82, 15.84, 15.78, 15.69, 15.59, 15.59, 15.59, 15.59, 15.59, 15.59, 15.68, 15.75, 15.76, 15.85, 15.93, 15.93, 15.9, 15.9, 15.93, 15.93, 15.95, 15.92, 16.01, 16.0, 15.81, 15.69, 15.68, 15.68, 15.74, 15.68, 15.65, 15.59, 15.54, 15.56, 15.67, 15.73, 15.79, 15.62, 15.54, 15.51, 15.58, 15.59, 15.61, 15.6, 15.58, 15.6, 15.59, 15.51, 15.51, 15.47, 16.71, 20.33, 23.75, 26.01, 27.26, 27.64, 27.92, 27.91, 27.62, 27.36, 26.99, 26.26, 25.6, 24.93, 24.15, 23.48, 22.57, 21.79, 21.03, 20.21, 19.55, 18.7, 17.98, 17.56, 17.03, 16.44, 16.04, 15.73, 15.4, 15.08, 14.85, 14.74, 14.67, 14.71, 14.88, 14.98, 15.36, 15.79, 16.21, 16.77, 17.12, 17.39, 17.49, 17.64, 17.74, 17.77, 17.89, 17.75, 16.9, 16.74, 16.49, 16.28, 16.21, 16.26, 16.18, 16.15, 16.17, 16.11, 16.1, 16.1, 16.02, 16.05, 16.02, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.03, 15.95, 15.93, 15.93, 15.86, 15.74, 15.7, 15.76, 15.86, 15.86, 15.93, 15.98, 15.86, 15.85, 15.78, 15.82, 15.92, 15.85, 15.85, 15.76, 15.7, 15.68, 15.82, 15.68, 15.68, 15.67, 15.75, 15.76, 15.82, 15.84, 15.85, 15.88, 15.9, 15.92, 15.91, 15.86, 15.84, 15.78, 15.66, 15.57, 15.47, 15.43, 15.49, 15.43, 15.38, 15.39, 15.28, 15.26, 15.26, 15.26, 15.3, 15.34, 15.3, 15.2, 15.19, 15.18, 15.17, 15.17, 15.09, 15.15, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.16, 15.09, 15.17, 15.17, 15.25, 15.26, 15.25, 15.26, 15.34, 15.2, 15.08, 15.0, 15.14, 15.23, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.31, 15.32, 15.26, 15.32, 15.34, 15.42, 15.34, 15.34, 15.4, 15.42, 15.5, 15.51, 15.58, 15.68, 15.68, 15.61, 15.59, 16.85, 20.48, 23.96, 26.26, 27.66, 28.12, 28.54, 28.79, 28.84, 28.98, 29.07, 28.94, 28.79, 28.74, 28.65, 28.45, 28.15, 27.9, 27.67, 27.44, 27.06, 26.69, 26.23, 25.97, 25.31, 24.88, 24.25, 23.58, 22.85, 22.25, 21.75, 21.15, 20.71, 20.32, 19.95, 19.67, 19.51, 19.5, 19.49, 19.5, 19.57, 19.82, 19.91, 19.84, 19.84, 19.82, 19.75, 18.59, 17.44, 17.01, 16.77, 16.63, 16.52, 16.44, 16.43, 16.43, 16.37, 16.34, 16.37, 16.4, 16.35, 16.34, 16.34, 16.28, 16.32, 16.27, 16.18, 16.23, 16.18, 16.2, 16.18, 16.2, 16.18, 16.19, 16.18, 16.17, 16.09, 16.01, 15.98, 16.01, 16.1, 16.15, 16.17, 16.18, 16.1, 16.1, 16.09, 16.09, 16.15, 16.18, 16.12, 16.03, 16.03, 16.09, 16.1, 16.1, 16.1, 16.09, 16.01, 16.08, 16.01, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 15.93, 16.0, 16.09, 16.09, 16.01, 15.99, 16.0, 16.09, 16.1, 16.09, 16.05, 16.01, 15.98, 15.95, 15.95, 15.92, 15.84, 15.76, 15.76, 15.78, 15.83, 15.75, 15.68, 15.69, 15.68, 15.68, 15.68, 15.7, 15.7, 15.68, 15.67, 15.81, 15.76, 15.76, 15.76, 15.83, 15.85, 15.76, 15.62, 15.59, 15.59, 15.6, 15.59, 15.53, 15.44, 15.39, 15.19, 14.91, 14.68, 14.38, 13.65, 13.65, 14.79, 17.48, 20.06, 21.8, 22.71, 22.96, 23.0, 22.92, 22.64, 22.39, 22.26, 21.73, 21.47, 21.2, 20.86, 20.74, 20.76, 20.6, 20.69, 20.75, 20.85, 20.96, 20.97, 21.17, 21.36, 21.53, 21.56, 21.62, 21.53, 21.37, 21.33, 21.19, 21.1, 20.92, 20.91, 20.71, 20.72, 20.6, 20.52, 20.51, 20.48, 20.42, 20.43, 20.51, 20.5, 20.5, 20.39, 18.88, 17.54, 17.04, 16.8, 16.69, 16.6, 16.48, 16.36, 16.41, 16.4, 16.43, 16.36, 16.29, 16.28, 16.26, 16.26, 16.26, 16.2, 16.18, 16.18, 16.1, 16.17, 16.18, 16.26, 16.34, 16.33, 16.34, 16.34, 16.43, 16.35, 16.34, 16.35, 16.35, 16.42, 16.43, 16.45, 16.38, 16.35, 16.33, 16.28, 16.26, 16.21, 16.26, 16.26, 16.33, 16.28, 16.35, 16.26, 16.21, 16.18, 16.17, 16.24, 16.19, 16.18, 16.18, 16.12, 16.1, 16.09, 16.1, 16.02, 15.99, 15.98, 16.0, 15.97, 15.96, 15.94, 15.95, 15.94, 15.93, 15.93, 15.87, 15.84, 15.84, 15.83, 15.73, 15.58, 15.57, 15.58, 15.46, 15.43, 15.23, 14.93, 14.53, 13.98, 13.35, 14.41, 16.87, 19.25, 20.56, 21.25, 21.24, 20.91, 20.75, 19.99, 19.56, 19.05, 18.33, 17.93, 17.21, 16.91, 16.91, 16.8, 17.13, 17.51, 18.09, 18.6, 19.1, 19.55, 19.88, 20.18, 20.25, 20.44, 20.51, 20.49, 20.49, 20.42, 20.41, 20.26, 20.15, 20.16, 20.04, 19.93, 19.95, 19.84, 19.89, 19.77, 19.76, 19.76, 19.74, 19.68, 19.67, 19.59, 18.44, 17.31, 16.85, 16.69, 16.53, 16.43, 16.33, 16.27, 16.22, 16.28, 16.18, 16.18, 16.18, 16.19, 16.26, 16.27, 16.25, 16.24, 16.26, 16.27, 16.26, 16.26, 16.18, 16.17, 16.18, 16.2, 16.21, 16.18, 16.18, 16.17, 16.1, 16.1, 16.1, 16.1, 16.03, 16.02, 16.02, 16.01, 16.03, 16.01, 15.98, 16.01, 16.01, 15.87, 15.83, 15.84, 15.91, 15.94, 16.01, 16.01, 16.01, 16.02, 16.02, 16.02, 16.09, 16.1, 16.04, 16.03, 16.02, 15.99, 16.01, 15.95, 15.93, 15.87, 15.85, 15.76, 15.69, 15.59, 15.46, 15.37, 15.33, 15.22, 15.1, 14.89, 14.59, 14.06])

signal = signal - np.average(signal)
amplitude = np.max(np.abs(signal))
signal = signal / amplitude
 
## data standadisation
N = len(signal) # signal as numpy array
phi_angles = []
n = 0 # sliding window
T = 166 # period of the signal
while (n + T < N):   # iterating signal, sample by sample, with a window of size T (period of the signal).  
        phi = np.angle(max_complex(np.fft.rfft(signal[n: n + T]))) # Find phase angle ([-pi to +pi]) made by the freq (complex number) of highest freq time_point in the window.
        phi_angles.append(phi)
        n += 1
plt.plot(range(len(signal)),signal)
plt.show()
plt.plot(range(len(phi_angles)),phi_angles)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The black circles are simply a fact of phase "wrapping".

By and large you are seeing linear phase but as soon as the phase increases past $\pi$, the `angle()` function maps it back to the interval $[-\pi,+\pi]$. The phase is periodic with $2\pi$ so the 181 degrees is the same angle as -179 degrees. That's exactly what you are seeing here.

I suggest looking at unwrapping the phase with something like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html

Comment: I understand that. But, what I fail to understand is why the phase is not starting from -179 degree as start of the signal is the start of the cycle. Instead the -179 degree is achieved at the middle of a cycle (marked by black circle).

Answer (score 0):

this is just a characteristic of your signal itself, so it would depend on where you got your test signal, whether synthetic or recorded. it is unlikely that you have the phase starting at -pi, like a synthetic sine wave where you have control over the synthesis